# webadmin deploy to azure from github

Tags: azure, deployment, virtocommerce

I'm trying to deploy webadmin to windows azure thru github 'Deploy to Azure'... I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error). error: "Unable to translate bytes [F3] at index 22 from specified code page to Unicode."

```
System.Text.DecoderFallbackException: Unable to translate bytes [F3]
     at index 22 from specified code page to Unicode.
     at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Throw(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
     at System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallbackBuffer.Fallback(Byte[] bytesUnknown, Int32 index)
     at System.Text.DecoderFallbackBuffer.InternalFallback(Byte[] bytes, Byte* pBytes, Char*& chars)
     at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetChars(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount, Char* chars, Int32 charCount, DecoderNLS baseDecoder)
     at System.Text.DecoderNLS.GetChars(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount, Char* chars, Int32 charCount, Boolean flush)
     at System.Text.DecoderNLS.GetChars(Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Int32 byteCount, Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex, Boolean flush)
     at System.Text.DecoderNLS.GetChars(Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Int32 byteCount, Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex)
     at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer(Char[] userBuffer, Int32 userOffset, Int32 desiredChars, Boolean& readToUserBuffer)
     at System.IO.StreamReader.Read(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadData(Boolean append, Int32 charsRequired)
     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal()
     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
     at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
     at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
     at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
     at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.<>c__DisplayClass8.<ReadFromStreamAsync>b__6()
     at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
     at Slingshot.Controllers.ARMController.<GetTenantsArray>d__67.MoveNext() in c:\code\GitHub\slingshot\Slingshot.Api\Controllers\ARMController.cs:line 436 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
     at Slingshot.Controllers.ARMController.<GetTemplate>d__4c.MoveNext() in c:\code\GitHub\slingshot\Slingshot.Api\Controllers\ARMController.cs:line 334
```

> Is it possible to install webadmin any other way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this is a bug in Azure related to Unicode characters in Azure Active Directory name. I was able to reproduce this error by adding the 'ó' character to my directory name.

I have posted an issue to their GitHub project:
https://github.com/projectkudu/slingshot/issues/32

As temporary workaround try to remove Unicode characters from your directory names in the Azure management portal. Please note that these changes may take some time.

It is possible to deploy webadmin manually but we have no corresponding documentation yet.

Comment: It's true.... by default the directory name created was "Diretório Padrão"... I'll try and let you know! Thanks!!!